# Chtome api tabs. Как получить url текущей вкладки в 3 версии манифеста

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, chrome-extension

Пишу расширение для хрома по доке, но не могу найти внятного примера как получить урл или другую инфу текущей вкладки. Поиск тоже не дал особого результата. Как я понимаю, версии манифестов достаточно сильно отличаются. Возможно, и не в них дело. Я бэкенд разработчик и  в js не очень силен, поэтому сори, если что. Буду рад любой помощи.

manifest.json

```
{
  "name": "ext_name",
  "description": "ext_description",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
  },
  "permissions": ["storage", "activeTab", "tabs"],
  "content_scripts": [
   {
     "matches": ["https://*"],
     "run_at": "document_idle",
     "js": ["add.js"],
     "css": ["button.css"]
   }
 ]
}
```

background.js

```
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(() => {});
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    var t = chrome.tabs.query({active: true, lastFocusedWindow: true});

    if (request.greeting === "hello")
      sendResponse({farewell: "goodbye", tab: t});
  }
);
```

add.js

```
let app = document.getElementById("app");

let div = document.createElement('div');
div.classList.add('iWant');
let text = document.createTextNode('iWant!');
div.appendChild(text);

app.before(div);

let iWantButton = document.getElementsByClassName('iWant');

iWantButton[0].addEventListener('click', function () {  
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({greeting: "hello"}, function(response) {
      console.log(response.tab);
    });
});
```

и в ответ приходит

```
{}
    [[Prototype]]: Object
        constructor: ƒ Object()
        hasOwnProperty: ƒ hasOwnProperty()
        isPrototypeOf: ƒ isPrototypeOf()
        propertyIsEnumerable: ƒ propertyIsEnumerable()
        toLocaleString: ƒ toLocaleString()
        toString: ƒ toString()
        valueOf: ƒ valueOf()
        __defineGetter__: ƒ __defineGetter__()
        __defineSetter__: ƒ __defineSetter__()
        __lookupGetter__: ƒ __lookupGetter__()
        __lookupSetter__: ƒ __lookupSetter__()
        __proto__: (...)
        get __proto__: ƒ __proto__()
        set __proto__: ƒ __proto__()
```

Не знаю что с этим делать. Подскажите, плз

Answer (score 0):

```
chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) {
        const tabId = tab.id;
        const tabUrl = tab.url;
    });
```

Обновленный для 3 версии - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/tabs/query

```
let querying = browser.tabs.query(queryObj)
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, добавьте к своему ответу дополнительную информацию. В текущем виде ваше решение сложно понять.

Comment: так ведь getSelected считается устаревшим в 3 версии манифеста. Или может дополните комментарий?

Comment: Вы правы, попробуйте данный подход, обновил ответ